# Listview in andengine

Tags: android, andengine

I want to implement a list like a leaderboard into my project. I saw an example which usw the Android native ListView class but is this the right way? Does any body know a solution?;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a solution but since you got no answer yet, I wanted to inform you that I used the native ListView class and it worked like a charm !

Easy to implement and I haven't heard about any other way to do so with Andengine yet (there might be though). This only is a return of experience, hope it helps !

Comment: Did you extends to the android activity class or how did you do this? ;)

Comment: I don't remember if I extended of if I used a ListActivity, if none of them work for you I'll look for that when back home on my Pc

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial that will demonstrate how to create, add and update ListViews:

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

After practicing the concepts in the tutorial, please keep in mind that every row in a list (a separate view) is recycled - while you do not need to inflate it again, you do need to ensure that you set/selete/update any and all information on it, otherwise you get funky bugs. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the approach from Google Play Game Services.

Your game activity can extend `AndEngine`'s `BaseGameActivity`. The leader-board activity can extend a normal `ListActivity`.

In your game start the leaderboards activity with `startActivityForResutl`. When the user is done, he just goes back to your game activity.